# undefined function: MyApp.Addict.Controller.init/1

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using addict with Phoenix: 1.0.3, I have followed README guide to use login in my app. I am getting following error when I make a call to login:

```
[error] #PID<0.2576.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /login
** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: MyApp.Addict.Controller.init/1 (module MyApp.Addict.Controller is not available)
MyApp.Addict.Controller.init(:login)
(my_app) web/router.ex:1: anonymous fn/1 in MyApp.Router.match/4
(my_app) lib/phoenix/router.ex:255: MyApp.Router.dispatch/2
(my_app) web/router.ex:1: MyApp.Router.do_call/2
(my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
(my_app) lib/plug/debugger.ex:90: MyApp.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
(my_app) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: MyApp.Endpoint.call/2
(plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
(cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This was due to my following error in `router.ex`:

```
  scope "/", MyApp do
    addict :routes
  end
```

This should had been:

```
  scope "/" do
    addict :routes
  end
```

Comment: In my case, it was the opposite: I forgot to add `MyApp` :) Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: I was having this issue while trying to use `OpenApiSpex.Plug.RenderSpec` and it kept failing with a cryptic error saying `MyApp.OpenApiSpex.Plug.RenderSpec.init/1` is unavailable. I had to remove `, MyApp` and it worked instantly.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the error was solved by running:

```
$ mix deps.compile --force
```

The controller that produced the errors had existed for a while and there was a controller test that didn't report any errors.

Comment: Solved it in my case. Probably the compiler got confused when I did some heavy git history rewriting.